# Cluster is not a type + cluster does not name a type error. Error for add(cluster *). Cant have cluster *?

Tags: c++, data-structures

```
class cluster{ //cluster is basically a tree
    int data;
    cluster *left;
    cluster *right; 
}
```

---

;
        };
               /cluster is a tree, queue is what i want to insert clusters into for       agglomerative clustering . I wanted to know why the void add and cluster* del are giving error

```
    class queue: public cluster{ //defining queue
        cluster *cluster;
        queue *next;
        public:
        void add(cluster*); //this gives error! Why? I ahve a datatype. 
        cluster* del(cluster*); //so does this
        void display();
        int size();
    }queue;
```

Comment: -1: poorly written and formatted. Also, you mentioned an error but didn't show the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `void add(cluster*)`, the name `cluster` resolves to the data member `queue::cluser`, not to the class name `::cluster`.

Avoid giving the same name to a type and to a variable. You are only confusing yourself.